# Meteor.js - is there any harm in storing *.less file outside of the client directory?

Tags: meteor

I have some `*.less` files, as well as some files that relate to them having to do with compiling Twitter Bootstrap, and I would like to store them all in a single `lib/` directory that also contains some shared resources such as `flow_router.js` and `mongo_collections.js`.

Currently I'm storing these `*.less` files in a `lib/` directory within my `client/` directory, but I think I would prefer to just have one `lib/` directory.

My concern is that there is some sort of performance overhead created by having these purely-client-side files also "running", so to speak, in the server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember, the Meteor build tool has a special case to ignore CSS files on the server, unless they are assets. This will still "waste" some resources compiling the less files to css, but I think this overhead is not worth caring about.